# Excel VBA running a macro across 50 sheets and applying a simple division

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run the following macro across 50 tabs. The Autofilter macro does work across the tabs but the macro where I want each figure to be divided by a total figure does not work. Basically, anything that starts from line 5 does not get applied to all tabs, it only applies to one tab. Can someone help?

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro

Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      ws.Range("A1:AC91").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("11" _
        , "21", "22", "23", "31-33", "42", "44-45", "48-49", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "61" _
        , "62", "71", "72", "81"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
         Range("AD1").Select
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "In %"
         Range("AD1").Select
         Selection.Font.Bold = True
         Range("AD2").Select
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/R2C28"
         Range("AD2").Select
         Selection.Copy
         Range("AD2:AD91").Select
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
         Selection.FillDown
         Selection.Style = "Percent"
         Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
         Selection.Font.Bold = True
         Range("AD2").Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Santosh for fixing the format of the code. May I ask how you did it so I know in the future?

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix every line starting with `Range`, with `ws.`, otherwise you are targeting the ActiveWorksheet, rather than the one in your loop.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro

Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      ws.Range("A1:AC91").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("11" _
        , "21", "22", "23", "31-33", "42", "44-45", "48-49", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "61" _
        , "62", "71", "72", "81"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
         ws.Range("AD1").Select
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "In %"
         ws.Range("AD1").Select
         Selection.Font.Bold = True
         ws.Range("AD2").Select
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/R2C28"
         ws.Range("AD2").Select
         Selection.Copy
         ws.Range("AD2:AD91").Select
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
         Selection.FillDown
         Selection.Style = "Percent"
         Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
         Selection.Font.Bold = True
         ws.Range("AD2").Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Or use a `With` block

Comment: I agree `With` that  ;-)

Comment: You can speed this up quit a bit, and avoid probable issues down the road, by getting rid of every instance of '.Select` and `.Selection`. Also, turning off `ScreenUpdating` would do some good here. +1

Comment: Hi, the above code returns the 1004 run-time error. I believe it is specifically for the code that is after the xfiltervalues command.

Comment: Have you tried what @urdearboy said ... Remove all the `.Select` statements?

Comment: Yes, I removed that. But the new error now is invalid use of property. Does that have to do with how the macro is named? I apologize for asking seemingly basic questions. Very new to the VBA programming space.

Comment: Ws.Range ("AD1"). Line 6.